How to train deep learning model without revealing plain dataset?
Suppose, there are two party, the dataset provider, which already annotated the ground truth (label) of the dataset and the trainer.
So, the dataset provider is already provided the ground truth and the input.
For concret example, the dataset is medical images.
The trainer is not supposed to know the plain dataset, even if the dataset is already obfuscated (e.g. full name of subject is converted to unique integer).
Since obfuscating doesn't mean encrypted, the trainer still know the medical image, he still able to load the medical image thought he doesn't know it's corresponded to whom.
So, how to make trainer just train the given tensor dataset input and the label without reveal plain image?
Mainly, How to make the dataset is able to learn by model but it's unable to load directly?
I think there must be a function to be passed for every data in dataset.
So, for every inference (using the trained model), incoming image must be passed into the function that act as encryptor.
Therefore, the model learned the encrypted dataset, not the plain dataset.
If plain dataset is fed to the model, the performance will be drop (this is expected) since the model learned the encrypted, not the plain.
So, only dataset provider known the function (encryptor) and its inverse (decryptor), the trainer doesn't know them.
